# run python app after server restart does not work using crontab

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, cron

I have a python application and I run it using `python app.py` but when the machine restart for any reason the application stoped

I searched and I found that I can make it run again using corn jobs

so I installed crontab and add the following code to it

```
@reboot /home/airnotifier/airnotifier/airnotifier.sh
```

and this is the code in the file `airnotifier.sh`

```
cd /home/airnotifier/airnotifier
python ./app.py
cd airnotifier
python ./app.py
cd /home/airnotifier/airnotifier
python app.py
cd airnotifier
python app.py
```

as you can see, I tried all combinations to make the application run again

can anyone tell me what did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I would try to just add this directly to the crontab

`@reboot python3 /home/airnotifier/airnotifier/app.py`

Unless you're on an older 2.x version of python, you should call it with `python3`

Comment: I tried it but it does not work