# how to make your python web app always running on ubuntu machine

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu

I have a web app that I deployed to a machine that has ubuntu 20 installed
to be able to run the app I should open ssh to the ubuntu machine and then run this command

```
cd mywebapp
python3 app.py
```

it works successfully, but once I close the ssh console or reboot the machine or anything happens, it stopped and I have to repeat these commands

I tried to add it as a corn job to be run after machine reboot but it does not work

I post a question in the following link : [run python app after server restart does not work using crontab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75025188/run-python-app-after-server-restart-does-not-work-using-crontab)

nothing work with me, and I have to make sure that this web app will always be running because it should be working to send push notification to mobile devices

can anyone please advice, I have been searching and trying for so many time

Comment: Have you tried systemd?

Comment: @sudden_appearance no, I did not, but I will give it a try

Comment: I solved it using the details in the following link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75058536/systemd-service-keep-giving-me-error-when-start-or-get-status

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not expert in it, but two solutions come in my mind:

**1- Using `systemd`:**

`systemd` can be responsible to keep services up.

You can write a custom unit for your app, and config it as a way to be up always.

This tutorial may be useful: [writing unit](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-create-systemd-service-unit-in-linux)

**2- Using `Docker`:**

When you have containerized app, you config it as to come up, on failure or anything like that.

Read about it [here](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/start-containers-automatically/#use-a-restart-policy)

Comment: I tried your first suggested way, but I still having a problem, I made a question about it, can you check please : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75058536/systemd-service-keep-giving-me-error-when-start-or-get-status

Comment: check the `journalctl -u airnotifier.service` to see if there is anything useful @AmiraElsayedIsmail

Answer (score 0):

What if you have the calling piece of Python script within a bash script and run that as a daemon:

Your bash script could like below (test.sh):

```
#!/bin/sh
cd desired/directory
python3 app.py
```

and you can run the bashscript like this by using `nohup`:

```
nohup ./test.sh 0<&- &>/dev/null &
```

You could refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10408816/how-do-i-use-the-nohup-command-without-getting-nohup-out), if you want to store the outputs of nohup.